# Why I cannot add new note after editing created one?

Tags: javascript, function, cycle

I cannot add new Note after editing. How can I exit from the cycle?
This is a part where I create a new note

```js
const createNote = () => {
  if (button.className === "button") {
    const div = document.createElement("div"); 
    div.setAttribute("class", "note");
    div.textContent = input.value;
    field.appendChild(div);
    
    const btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.setAttribute("class", "edit");
    btn.textContent = "Edit";
    div.appendChild(btn);
    
    const del = document.createElement("button");
    del.setAttribute("class", "del");
    del.textContent = "Delete";
    div.appendChild(del);
    console.log("Note has been created");
    input.value = "";
  }
```

Here is a part where I want to edit created Note but also I want to create a new one (this part is inside function createNote)

```
  const edit = document.querySelectorAll(".edit");

  for (let i of edit) {
    i.onclick = () => {
      input.value = i.previousSibling.nodeValue;
      button.innerText = "Edit";
      button.classList.add("editable");
      /*button.classList.remove("button");*/

      if (button.className === "button editable") {
        button.onclick = () => {
          i.previousSibling.nodeValue = input.value;
          input.value = "";
          button.classList.remove("editable");
          button.classList.add("button");
          button.innerText = "Add";
        };
      }
    };
  }
};

button.onclick = createNote;
```

Here is HTML that I am using

```html
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="insert">
            <input type="text" name="Note" id="noteId" placeholder="add note">
            <button class="button">Add</button>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <div class="note">Test note
                <button class="edit">Edit</button>
                <button class="del">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: You have some `undefined` in your code, yet you overwrite the `button.onclick` event, which might be the cause of it not creating more notes. A runable example would be appreciated.

Comment: there is no button or field element defined in your code....  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Kindly add your HTML code, and if possible the rest of your Javascript code

Comment: had updated with HTML

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the po has disappeared, is it really useful to keep such a badly asked question ?, in more than a year the PO must be moved on, and this question obviously has no interest for him too